# Encontrar registros entre um range de segundos

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela onde o campo data contém data completa (com segundos), eu preciso com uma dada data, buscar todos os registros com 10 segundos acima e 10 segundos abaixo, a query que tentei fazer é essa:

```sql
SELECT DATA FROM deals WHERE direcao = 'in' AND DATA BETWEEN CAST(ADDTIME('2019-04-04 10:45:00', '10') AS DATETIME) AND CAST(SUBTIME('2019-04-04 10:45:00', '10') AS DATETIME);
```

Mas por algum motivo não retorna nada, tenho algumas linhas dentro desse range de 20 segundos, mas não retorna nada, tenho a impressão que o problema seja o tipo dos dados.

Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você inverteu o `ADDTIME` e `SUBTIME` no `BETWEEN`, da forma que esta você está buscando todos os registros de `2019-04-04 10:45:10` até `2019-04-04 10:44:50`. Por isso sua consulta não esta retornando nada:

```
SELECT `DATA`
FROM deals
WHERE `DATA` BETWEEN SUBTIME('2019-05-04 17:36:15', 10) AND ADDTIME('2019-05-04 17:36:15', 10);
```

OBS: Não é necessário fazer o `CAST`.

Veja funcionando no [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e7306/3).